# How to loop through every 50 rows in r?

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to get results for the rows 1:50, 51:100, 101:150. This would clearly be more efficient with a loop than writing the same code thrice.

My idea was this:

```
a <- c(1:50,51:100,101:150)

for (i in a) {
as.matrix(dist(iris[i,2]), method = "euclidian")
}
```

But it doesn't work, I get no output. This does work though:

```
as.matrix(dist(iris[1:50,2]), method = "euclidian")
```

Does someone know how to code that loop rightly?

Comment: It probably works, it's just doesn't print. Enclose it in a `print` function within the loop. Though just printing it won't help you. Create a vector and save the results by iteration and then print the results to check it out

Comment: Hi Egon and welcome! A few things that may help: (1) you aren't assigning anything in your loop, that's why you  arent getting anything returned. (2) your `a` values are identical to `a <- 1:150` - in this context there is no benefit breaking them up into 1:150, 51:100, etc. You would want `a <- list(1:50,51:100,101:150)` (3) Typo in `as.matrix(dist(iris[1:50,2]), method = "euclidian")`? Parentheses are off. (4) whats your desired output? ie, a list of length three containing the results of 1:50, 51:100, and 101:150?  A little bit more clarity may help us get you the help you need!

Comment: @DavidArenburg It definitely doesn’t work, because `a` is a vector. It would need to be a list instead.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Perhaps, I haven't tested it

Comment: @jpsmith Thx, making `a` a list worked

Answer (score 1):

One way to code this loop is to use a list to define `a`:

```
a <- list(1:50,51:100,101:150)

 # or more generally:
a <- split(seq(nrow(iris)), ceiling(seq(nrow(iris))/50))
```

and assign the values to a new list (`newlist`). If you wanted to do a `for` loop as your question asks, that would be:

```
newlist <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(a))

for(x in seq_along(a)){
  newlist[[x]] <- as.matrix(dist(iris[a[[x]], 2], method = "euclidian"))
}
```

Though you could do this using `lapply`:

```
lapply(a, \(x) as.matrix(dist(iris[x, 2], method = "euclidian")))
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the title of your question, you want to loop by "**every 50 rows**".

---

You can try `tapply` with `ceiling` like below

```
tapply(
    iris[, 2],
    ceiling(seq_len(nrow(iris)) / 50),
    \(x) as.matrix(dist(x), method = "euclidian")
)
```

where `ceiling(seq_len(nrow(iris)) / 50)` split rows into groups by every 50 rows.

---

Or, you should specify row groups in a list for `a`, e.g., `a <- list(1:50,51:100,101:150)`, then do the `for` loop.

```
a <- list(1:50, 51:100, 101:150)
res <- list()
for (i in a) {
    res <- append(res, list(as.matrix(dist(iris[i, 2]), method = "euclidian")))
}
```

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with showing multiple methods, but the answer makes it sound as if `tappy()` can only be used with the `ceiling()` method, and the manual `for` loop can only be used with a hard-coded list of limits. Whereas of course these are completely orthogonal. — And, as an aside, `append()` is a really misleadingly-named `insert()` function. The *actual* “append” operation in R is performed by `c()`, and *it* should be used in place of `append()` everywhere except when you actually specify an `after` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Using `c()` everything became a single atomic vector `1,2...150` and you're iteration goes row by row instead of groups. Using `list()` they are not concatenated. Then what do you want to do with the results... print or store them? The following stores the results in a list:

```
a <- list(1:50,51:100,101:150)

result <- list()
for (row_group in a) {
  result[[paste(head(row_group, 1), "to", tail(row_group, 1))]] <- 
    as.matrix(dist(iris[i,2]), method = "euclidian")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
n <- 3
m <- dim(iris)[1]/n
a <- lapply(m*(seq_len(n) - 1), `+`, 1:m)
r <- lapply(a, \(i) as.matrix(dist(iris[i, 2])))
```

### Gives

```
str(r)
# List of 3
 # $ : num [1:50, 1:50] 0 0.5 0.3 0.4 0.1 0.4 0.1 0.1 0.6 0.4 ...
 #  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 #  .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 #  .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 # $ : num [1:50, 1:50] 0 0 0.1 0.9 0.4 ...
 #  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 #  .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 #  .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 # $ : num [1:50, 1:50] 0 0.6 0.3 0.4 0.3 ...
 #  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 #  .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 #  .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```